# What should I look for in an electric steamer for use to make tamales

Tags: steaming, tamales

I don't know a whole lot about what makes an electric steamer a good steamer. I'm looking for recommendations for one where I'm hoping to make [tamales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamale) with. The plan is to make large batches so capacity is definitely a concern. Would the multi-level steamers work?

Any specific recommendations would be great. Any suggestions on what features to look for would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never cooked tamales before, but when looking for something that needs to get hot (griddle, waffle iron, steamer)

- Get something made out of metal. Plastic will not get as hot and will warp over time.
- Avoid Low/Med/High dials, get something that will tell you the actual temperature.
- Even heat distribution is key. Make sure the element/steam is not lopsided.

Some things that I would go for would be a glass top, a digital dial, and a safety power cord that detaches from the unit if yanked.

Comment: Ended up getting this one (http://www.amazon.com/Secura-Stainless-Electric-technology-S-324/dp/B004MKG8H8/ref=sr_1_10?s=kitchen&ie=UTF8&qid=1340236175&sr=1-10&keywords=steamer). It's worked out nice.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips which I found on [Consumer Mentor](https://www.consumermentor.com/best-tamale-steamer/):

- High-gauge aluminum and stainless steel both provide a robust, lightweight, and easy to clean material for tamale steamers
- Riveted handles are a good feature as they don't get too hot
- A glass lid can be good as it allows you to see inside the pot without releasing the steam
- As far as size is concerned each quart will fit around 3 tamales, so you should calculate your required size based on that.